# Java Swing realtime change componente

Tags: java, swing

Is there a possibility using Java Swing to add in a existing running Swing application a button as an example. The action of the button to have a call to an existing method in that application. Maybe using xml to define the structure of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. When any action triggered you can create the button and set the listener for it.

But best practice is to create the button and listener at the build time. Here you need to hide/set visibility to false initially and when any action triggered, set the visibility to true.

Comment: somenthing like thins I want to do https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071777/design-patterns/add-dynamic-java-code-to-your-application.html?page=2

Comment: Now I got your concern. Can't you create a structure for XML in such a way that you know the syntax of the XML before you run your application so that you can implement the application to parse the XML, get the required information from it and render to the application? Simple Example: Your input XML may look like this, <input> <component type="button" name="b1" label="b1"> <action type="invoke_existing_method">method_name/method_id</action> </component> </input>

Comment: Now challenge here is how to call exiting method, for this you can either create the interface/Factory for all the methods that to be invoked. Based on the action, method name or method id you can call them.

If You want to execute user input code then I suggest you use JS instead Java.